# Interacting with Helm chart 3 using REST APIs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using Django RESTful and I want a way that I can interact with helm charts using APIs or any other way that can let me send requests for creating, managing, and manipulating the charts. I have tried searching for answers here and most of them are outdated. So I am hoping there has come a solution in between those years.

Comment: Helm v3 doesn't have an in-cluster component or a long-running server, so there's no HTTP endpoint you could call.  There's a [Go SDK](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#go-sdk), and in principle you can bridge to it from other languages, but shelling out to `helm` commands might be the best approach.